# Sonal lint : change this condition so that it does not always evaluate to true

Tags: java, spring, jpa, sonarqube, sonarlint

I am trying to consume Data JPA Repository from From Java Service which is something like below:

```
@Service
public class APIKeyServiceImpl implements APIKeyService {

    private APIKeyRepo apiKeyRepo;

    @Autowired
    public APIKeyServiceImpl(APIKeyRepo apiKeyRepo) {
        this.apiKeyRepo = apiKeyRepo;
    }


    @Override
    public String save(String apiKeyInput) {

        APIKEY apikey = new APIKEY();
        apikey.setApikey(apiKeyInput);

        APIKEY savedKey = apiKeyRepo.save(apikey);

        return null != savedKey ? savedKey.getApikey() : null;
    }

}
```

Now Short Repo Code is below:

```
public interface APIKeyRepo extends JpaRepository<APIKEY, String> {

}
```

Problem is whenever I run Sonarlint Report then I am getting below major issue:

**change this condition so that it does not always evaluate to true**

Which is occurring at ternary operator code which is :

```
return null != savedKey ? savedKey.getApikey() : null;
```

I havn't much understand which part of this will always evaluate **true**.

Comment: I suppose Repository always returns non-null value:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/CrudRepository.html#save-S-

Comment: Why would you think (in what conditions) that `savedKey` is null?

Comment: @AlexanderTerekhov -  Thanks , Noted.

Comment: @ScaryWombat -  I actually assumed that JPA might give null result. I was wrong.

Comment: When you saving an entity you will always get saved entity in return that is why it can not be a null Object anytime!

Comment: I am glad that sonar is able to understand and simulate rule for standard data jpa mechanism

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Documentation]

As you save an entity save method will return you the saved entity, which can never be null.

Source: Method Doc.